# Stop and think: Hip to the Squares? from The Algorithm Design Manual, 2nd Edition

Tags: algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics

Currently I'm reading *The Algorithm Design Manual, 2nd Edition*, by Steven Skiena and I stumbled upon a problem.

In Chapter 2, where he explains algorithm analysis, which includes Big Oh notation, I don't understand his solution to *Stop and Think: Hip to the Squares?*

*Problem: Is (x + y)<sup>2</sup> = O(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>).*

His solution is that (x + y)<sup>2</sup> <= 3(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>), which means c >= 3 (constant from the definition of Big Oh).

Here is my solution:

1. (x + y)<sup>2</sup> <= c(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>)
2. x<sup>2</sup> + 2xy + y<sup>2</sup> <= c(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>)
3. x = max(x, y)
4. x<sup>2</sup> + 2x<sup>2</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> <= c(x<sup>2</sup> + x<sup>2</sup>)
5. 4x<sup>2</sup> <= 2cx<sup>2</sup>
6. 2x<sup>2</sup> <= cx<sup>2</sup>
7. c >= 2

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where he got the 3, but here's how one can show that (x + y)<sup>2</sup> <= 2(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>):

2(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>) - (x + y)<sup>2</sup> = 2x<sup>2</sup> + 2y<sup>2</sup> - x<sup>2</sup> -2xy - y<sup>2</sup>
 = x<sup>2</sup> - 2xy + y<sup>2</sup> = (x - y)<sup>2</sup> >= 0

As for why your solution is wrong, you're starting from what you want to prove, which is tricky.  I like to put a question mark next to the inequality as a reminder that it's not yet known:

1. (x + y)<sup>2</sup> <=? c(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>)

And then each following step should be one that implies the previous step, so that if you reach a definitely true statement, you can reverse the steps and have a proof.  The next step is fine:

2. x<sup>2</sup> + 2xy + y<sup>2</sup> <=? c(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>)

Now your step 3 is neither something you want to prove nor something you know to be true.  What you can say is that everything is symmetric in x and y, so we may assume that x = max(x, y) (because if y were the greater one, you could do whatever you were going to do but with x and y swapped).

But as Douglas Zare points out, step 4 is not equivalent to step 2, because you increased both sides of an inequality.

Answer (score 1):

First, the exact constant usually isn't important. One point of using this type of asymptotic analysis is that it is simpler than the exact analysis used by Knuth, Flajolet and Sedgewick, and others. So, even if you find that 3 is not the best constant possible, so what?

Second, you made a mistake that would be easier to catch if instead of simply writing a bunch of equations hoping that they are self-evident, you wrote out the logical connections. It's like commenting your code.

You want to choose c so that the inequality is true. This means your implications are supposed to be upwards: 7 implies 6 implies 5 implies 4 implies 2 implies 1. However, you replaced both the left hand side of 2 with a larger expression and the right hand side of 2 with a larger expression to get inequality 4. The second part would be valid for a downward implication, but not an upward implication. With more work, you can still establish a better constant, but you haven't justified this so your derivation is incomplete.

I presume that the book's solution is that if c>=1, c(x^2+y^2) >= cx^2+y^2. If c>=3 and x>=y, then cx^2 >= x^2+2xy so cx^2+y^2 >= x^2+2xy+y^2.

Comment: In reaching cx^2 >= x^2+2xy, I think you assumed x >= 0.  I don't see where that was given in the problem.

Comment: @JWWalker: No, it's not required that x>=0. What I used was that |x|>=|y|. In CS, people generally don't care about negative variables in asymptotic analysis anyway.